# Integration of PostGIS with JHipster

Tags: java, postgresql, jhipster, postgis, jdl

We have currently a rather convoluted way of using the Geometry fieldtype of PostGIS with JHipster (4.6, currently trying to upgrade to 4.14 - which is not going smoothly - will probably post another question for this)

1. we added hibernate-spatial and liquibase-spatial to pom.xml

   then create the jdl Entities with String fields,

   import this with "jhipster import-jdl database.jdl"

   then change the entities to


       `@Column(name = "geometry", columnDefinition="Geometry") 
       private Geometry geometry`

   mvnw compile liquibase:diff

   add reference to the generated change logs in master.xml

   remove statements that drop spatial tables in the generated change logs

and i probably forgot some steps inbetween...

Q: Is there a better way to integrate postgis into jhipster ?

In github i only found that the jhipster team does not want to integrate support for GIS Extensions into JHipster/JDL because they are not available everywhere.

Comment: At my company, Ippon which is the birthplace of JHipster we have already done a project integrating PostGIS and JHipter. Please have a look at this blog post (in french sorry) : http://blog.ippon.fr/2017/12/04/la-technologie-spatiale-au-service-de-jhipster/
I was not involved in the project itself so I cannot give you more info but I think that you need to define your liquibase changelog manually to resolve your issues.

Comment: @PierreBesson : Thanks for the article. I think it is more or less doing the same steps like us. We change the liquibase changelog in steps 5-7.

Comment: continued... As we use JDL to define the entities we have to create the field with a type that JDL understands (e.g. String) and then have to change it to the real Geometry type.